# Regarding a C Program of star pattern

Tags: c

if i give an input of 13, output should be like:

```
*

**

***

****

***
```

i've reached only this far:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()

{
    int i, j, n = 13;
    for(i = 1 ; i <= n ; i++)
    {
        for ( j = 1; j <= i ; j++)
        {
            printf("*");
        }
        t = ((i * (i + 1)) / 2);
        printf("\n");
    }
    printf("%d",t);
    return 0;
}
```

stars should be increasing by 1 in every line, but program will stop when total printed stars reach my inputted number. i am not sure how to start and where to end. i am very new to "for" loops.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this

```
     int n,i=1,j,coun=0;
     scanf("%d",&n);
     while(1)
     {
         if(i+coun<=n)
         {
              for(j=0;j<i;j++)
                  printf("*");
              printf("\n");
              coun+=i;
         }
         else
         {
            for(j=0;j<n-coun;j++)
               printf("*");
            printf("\n");
            break;
         }
         i++;
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    int i, j, k, n = 13;
    for(k = j = i = 1 ; i <= n ; i++, j++){
        putchar('*');
        if(j==k){
            putchar('\n');
            j = 0;
            ++k;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```